# Why does gcc compiler behave differently in these two cases?

Tags: c, gcc, while-loop, compiler-optimization

I have two similar while loops and am curious why C compiler behaves differently in each case.

**Details: Compiler: x86-64 gcc 8.2**

**Options: -O3**

```
void use() 
{ 
    int* ptr;
    while (*ptr == 6);
}

Assembly:

use:
        cmp     DWORD PTR ds:0, 6
        jne     .L1
.L3:
        jmp     .L3
.L1:
        ret
```

As we see, the compiler still generates an infinite loop. However, if I use this:

```
void use() 
{ 
    int p;
    while (p == 6);
} 

Assembly:

use:
        ret
```

I expected both of them to generate no while loop. My guess is that, for 1st version, since we cannot possibly know what ptr points to, we cannot assume anything about *ptr. But could we make a similar argument for the 2nd version, where p is just a local variable, i.e. p could contain anything?

Comment: This is a compiler-specific question, as such you should say which compiler you are using.

Comment: Additionally, they are both undefined behaviour so you have no reason to expect they will do anything sensible - unless your compiler vendor documents a specific contractual behaviour.

Comment: Undefined behavior is behavior which is undefined... Why do you care about how the compiler optimizes bugs?

Comment: Compiler version? What other options are you specifying? What architecture? x86? x64? Arm? Answer can be different for each.

Comment: @Lundin just out of curiosity.

Comment: Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" …. Doctor: "Then don't do that".... You are not solving a real problem, so the answer is "undefined behaviour is undefined". Or to put it another way "who cares?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions have **Undefined Behavior** because you access and read uninitialized variables. As such the compiler can generate **any** code.

Comment: This answer only states why the C standard **permits** a compiler to generate any code. That does not explain why a compiler **does** generate the code it does. The C standard is **not the only criterion** for compiler behavior. Another is that the compiler ought to optimize code. Wherever the C standard gives latitude for different implementations, a compiler, when optimization is enabled, ought to choose the more optimized code. Generating a compare and two branches when a single `ret` (or trap) could have been generated is sub-optimal. So this indicates some shortcoming in the compiler.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I disagree. You can't say that a code generated for UB is suboptimal. UB code is illegal. A valid program will never execute UB code. So what are the criterias for optimizing illegal code?

Comment: Undefined behavior is not illegal. Nothing in the C standard prohibits a program from executing behavior not defined by the C standard. Aside from extensions (which the C standard invites), undefined behavior nominally arises in code paths where some hypothetical set of circumstances could produce undesired behavior on one code path given a particular program state, but the program never executes that path with that state (due to choices made elsewhere). In such cases, the compiler ought to know the code path with undefined behavior may be assumed to never execute and can be reduced.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The compiler is only obligated to do what it promises to do. Unless it documents that it has a particular behaviour for a particular case of undefined behaviour, you have no reason to expect it will do anything in particular.

Comment: @Ben: The `-O3` and `-Os` switches are documented as optimizing for time or space, respectively, but almost nothing is said about what optimizations are performed or how well the compiler does them. In fact, they have generally gotten better, considerably so, over the years. We do know that `-O3` is supposed to optimize for time (and for space when it does not affect time), so generating instructions that take more time when it could have generated instructions that take less time is a shortcoming. There is a documented goal (optimize for time), and the compiler failed to meet that goal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No.

Comment: @Ben: Additionally, as I wrote earlier, the presence of undefined behavior on a code path allows the compiler to assume that code path is not taken. In such circumstances, the compiler ought to reduce that code path, as by generating no code for it and eliminating the branch that would have taken that path. E.g., if you see a pointer used on a code path that was earlier set to `NULL` and not changed, you can assume that path is not executed. This optimization of undefined behavior is an integral part of optimization.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes in theory, but no in practice, so no. And No.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184145/discussion-between-ben-and-eric-postpischil).

Comment: @Ben: Yes in practice. My knowledge of this stems from an example I saw in some technical GCC/Clang discussion (a defect report if memory serves) that I saw long ago. It was drawn from real world code, and the gist of it was that various optimization had resulted in code equivalent to `p = NULL; if (x == 0) A(*p) else B();`. Upon reaching this state, we see that `*p` has undefined behavior. Then the compiler ought to deduce that `A` is not called and `x` cannot be zero. Instead of generating any code to call `A`, the compiler ought to eliminate the test and the call and merely evaluate `B();`.

Comment: @Ben: It is interesting because, in this case, the “undefined behavior” of `A(*p)` is actually `B();`. That is, this shows how having undefined behavior in one expression can not merely trap or overflow or whatever but can actually, in practice, result in evaluating a completely different expression. But, aside from that, the point is we do not want a compiler that, for undefined behavior, merely does anything. We want the compiler to use it to make further optimizations. It produces better results, in actual practice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil please stop spamming comments here. A chat was created for this thread.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what the compiler may do, what it ought to do, and what it does do can be completely different things. Optimising on undefined behaviour has been a source of serious security bugs.

Comment: @Ben: By arguing against optimizing on undefined behavior, you contradict your earlier statement that one has no reason to expect the compiler to do anything in particular for undesired behavior. If you cannot expect anything in particular, you cannot expect it not to optimize. In any case, my objection to this answer stands: There is a **reason** the compiler behaved differently, and what the C standard says is inadequate to explain it. It does appear the compiler failed to recognize the undefined behavior in the first code and mindlessly implemented it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil we are in chat now. Stop spamming comments here.

Comment: @Ben: I am not available for chat.